# Modifying Bootstrap form's submit button to custom css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I have been learning from and using elements of Hartl's [Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec-following_and_followers_pages) for my own app and learning experience.  In the tutorial, in order to follow a user, the default option has been clicking through a Bootstrap-Sass button alongside Rails' `form_for` helper as seen below:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

However, I'd like to modify the input as a custom button, and changing the class from `btn btn-large btn-primary` to `.follow-button`.

My CSS for `follow-button` as follows.  As noted in the comments, I have having trouble modifying basic elements like the transparency and font size and color (the font seem to default to the basic Bootstrap font), while other elements, such as the hover aspect does function. How do I override some of the default Bootstrap settings for forms so that all my custom elements come out?  Thanks!

```
.follow-button{
     background: transparent;
     border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
     display: block;
     float: right;
      &:hover { 
      background: #0089d1;
    }
      a {
      color: #006faa;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 1.4em; //font size does not change
      display: block;
      padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px; //modification doesn't show..
      text-decoration: none;
      &:hover { 
      color: rgb(229, 246, 255);
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Edits:**

With the updated CSS code:

```
.follow-button{
     background: transparent;
     border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
     display: block;
     float: right;
      &:hover { 
      background: #0089d1;
    }
    input[type='submit'] {
      color: #006faa;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 1.4em; //font size does not change
      display: block;
      padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px; //modification doesn't show..
      text-decoration: none;
      &:hover { 
      color: rgb(229, 246, 255);
      }
    }
  }
```

The Rails submit form:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @course.id)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "follow-button" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you have tried '!important' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are styling a `.follow-button` that contains a link (`a`). but `f.submit` creates a input type of submit. Since there is now "a", it would never match your style selectors.

```
<%= f.submit "Follow", class: "follow-button" %>
```

and then

```
.follow-button{
     background: transparent;
     border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
     display: block;
     float: right;
      background: #0089d1;
      color: #006faa;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 1.4em; //font size does not change
      display: block;
      padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px; //modification doesn't show..
      text-decoration: none;
      &:hover { 
        color: rgb(229, 246, 255);
        background: #0089d1;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I pasted the code in, but the changes still didn't take effect.  Restarting the rails server did not help either..

Comment: I updated the body of the question with the updated code...thanks for following up.  Just for the sake of trying options (my CSS-fu is weak..), I also tried `input[name='commit']` which did not work.

Comment: Ahhh, yes, it's because the input IS the follow-button. updated